# how to store current user data in mongodb while using firebase authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on a MERN app and using firebase authentication at the client side.

When a user is logging in for the first time, then that user's info(from firebase) will be saved in the database.

```
export const startLogIn = () =>{
   return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleAuthProvider)
            .then(result => {
            if(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){
                console.log(result.user);
                axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/user`, result.user)
                    .then(() => console.log(newUser.data))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))  
            }else{
                console.log('existing user');
            }
        });
};
```

And in app.js I am fething the user data from database

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if(user){ 
 store
 .dispatch(usersFetchData(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/${user.uid}`));
  store.dispatch(startSetPost()).then(() => {
  renderApp();
  if(history.location.pathname === '/'){
    history.push('/dashboard');
  } 
});
} 
  else{
   console.log('log out');
   store.dispatch(logout());
   renderApp();
   history.push('/');
}
});
```

But the the strategy is not working as axios request is async, so before 
 completion of the post request, the app.js dispacthing function starts running.

Comment: Instead of sending the dispatch after a Firebase `onAuthStateChanged`, why not do it in the `then()` function of the axios post so it only happens after?

Comment: It will not full fill the requirements because this startlogin func only runs when user log in the browser. Suppose you logged in and then close the tab without logging out. Next when you will again open the site, you will be directly redirected to the dashboard page. In that case you will not get the user data.